# PackageReference Versioning Wildcard csproj

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task, packagereference

I have the following in my NetStandard Project

```
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="MyReference" Version="1.0.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

When I change it to use the wildcard (instead of 1.0.1) I get an exclamation mark on the dependencies toggle, then the NuGet toggle and then of course the package itself.

When I check in, the CI build also fails on the other end, giving me

> Unable to find package MyReference. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages, nuget.org

All of the above issues disappear when using the actual version with no wildcard (1.0.1), but I want to ensure that the .NET Core Restore Task, always restores to the latest package, and I was hoping a simple wildcard would do it.

NB - I am using my own private NuGet repository (Package Management Extension)

Please advise.

Why would using a wildcard fail during the CI build, indicating that it can't find the package?

So let's say I have project1 deployed to my own NuGet repository. Project2 has a dependency on Project1, which has been added as a NuGet package to Project2. Project1 package resides, without issue nor error in my own repository.

When I use the wildard and build locally, it works, and restores the latest version. When I check in the code changes (with wildcard left in the .csproj) - CI Build fails with the aforementioned error message.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. What're tasks of your build/release definition? Set system.debug variable to true, then queue a new build and share this log here. You may share a sample project that can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `[1.0,1.1)`?

Comment: Did you end up solving this issue? I'm encountering this right now.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards)

> When using the PackageReference format, NuGet also supports using a
>   wildcard notation, *, for Major, Minor, Patch, and pre-release suffix
>   parts of the number. Wildcards are not supported with the
>   `packages.config` format.

### For your question

> Always specify a version or version range for package dependencies in
>   project files, `packages.config` files, and `.nuspec` files. Without a
>   version or version range, **NuGet 2.8.x** and earlier chooses the **latest
>   available package version** when resolving a dependency, whereas **NuGet
>   3.x** and later chooses the **lowest package version**. Specifying a version or version range avoids this uncertainty.

Comment: Hi Yes - I have read this doc. I'm not sure if I have missed something, but I'm not too sure how this helps me? I'm using PackageReference in my csproj